# Magento Give onhover title text popup in navigatoion menu

Tags: magento

Currently i'm using magento 1.6.1.0. I'm having 6 categories. While onhover to any category i want some text to be appear. Lets say my first category is furniture, while taking my cursor to that furniture menu i want the text "click to see our furniture colections" to appear as small popup test. Usually in html i'll do this using title="click to see our furniture colections".

But here in php i dono how to do. So far i found the phtml file from where the categories are calling. from app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml

Plz tell me how to do this..

Answer (score 0):

First, my answer **is not a good approach** to resolve your issue, but it will do it. The good approach is to override a block, not to edit the core one.

edit the file **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php** find the line
*$html[] = 'getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';*
 (for me is line 286)
transform it into 
*$html[] = 'escapeHtml($category->getName()).' collection" href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';*

Answer (score 0):

For this you should have some knowledge about Magento.

Open the file *app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php* and go the line 286.

```
$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
```

You should change this line to

```
$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.' title="click to see our '. $$this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) .' colections">';
```